# On a French diploma, why are some decrees timestamped, while others are not?

Tags: france, academia

I have noticed that on some French diploma, some decrees timestamped, while others are not. Why?

Example

[image]

In the red rectangle, the first line refers to a decree without mentioning its date, while the second line refers to a decree mentioning its date. The two lines can be vaguely translated as follows:

> With regard to the decree 2002-481, respecting the university titles
>   and levels, and national diplomas; 
> With regard to the decree 2002-590
>   passed on April 24, 2002, which enforces the first paragraph of the
>   article L. 613.3 and the article L. 613-4 of the Education Code and
>   relating to the validation by Higher Education institutions of the
>   knowledge acquired by experience;

Comment: Because someone forgot to add the date? Note that the information is actually redundant, the number by itself is enough to uniquely identify it (as you can check on www.legifrance.gouv.fr). It's a matter of usage to include the date, but that does not actually define it any further (it might help if either the number or the date has a typo). An even better way of referencing it would be the NOR, but nobody uses that for unknown reason (read: inertia).